# paper-header-panel content div behaving erratically

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am doing a simple test of polymer 1.0 elements. In the paper-header-panel test, the content area elements are not visible or are moving over the paper-header div. The demo is [here](http://recipestore.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/) and the code is below. Why is the content text not being displayed?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>paper-header-panel demo</title>

    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
  </head>

  <body class="fullbleed layout vertical" style="height: 100%">
      <paper-header-panel mode="waterfall" class="flex">
        <div class="paper-header" style="height: 60px;">I am the header</div>
        <div class="content fit">I am the content</div>
      </paper-header-panel>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here might be your problem.

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
```

Try changing this to

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html">
```

The previous one contains only the layout mixins (which is actually the recommended one), while the latter contains the layout classes (along with the `/deep/` selectors) that you seemed to be using.

Comment: That didn't make any difference to the output. I have made the change and the output is still the same.

Comment: That's because you set the body to have a 100% height. The `fullbleed` class uses 100vh. Try to remove the inline style of the body.

Answer (score 2):

Add `<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html">` and remove the style attribute out of the body:

```
<body class="fullbleed layout vertical">
  <paper-header-panel mode="waterfall" class="flex">
    <div class="paper-header" style="height: 60px;">I am the header</div>
    <div class="content fit">I am the content</div>
  </paper-header-panel>
</body>
```

Typically the paper-toolbar component is used inside the paper-header-panel which imports the paper-style for you.

Comment: how come they didn't have to use the `class="fullbleed layout vertical"` and `class="flex"` at https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-header-panel/blob/master/demo/index.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add `class="fit"` to `<paper-header-panel>`?